# Handling room changes with slam_gmapping

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [gmapping package](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) implements an easy-to-use SLAM algorithm, but it seems to assume a static environment. If the room changes for any reason, it easily confuses the algorithm. How do you allow a robot to maintain its map but also handle events like, a door being closed or a person walking infront of the laser scanner, without gmapping getting lost or destroying its map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241900/handling-room-changes-with-slam_gmapping/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, `gmapping` is quite stable, when configured correctly, with respect to changes in the environment.

Typically, you only map once and the use localization on the created map using e.g. `amcl` which is even more agnostic to changes.

But you are right, if the environment changes much during mapping, these are just not the right algorithms. You would need to use other algorithms providing long-term mapping capabilities. But AFAIK there are currently non available in ROS.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0